# Можно ли выключить все button элементы каким-либо циклом?

Tags: c#, winforms

Представим, что у меня 200 кнопок и в один момент мне нужно скрыть все 200 кнопок. Можно ли задать параметр button.Visible = false всем кнопкам, не прописывая при этом 200 строчек по типу button(1, 2, 3, 4 и т.д.).Visible = false? Например каким-нибудь циклом for, foreach и т.д.?

Comment: у вас есть форма, у формы есть какое то свойство (если я верно помню, что то типа Children), вы можете по этому свойству пройтись циклом и найти все кнопки, вложенные непосредственно в форму.

Comment: @tym32167 `Controls`, but it has to be done recursively, if buttons have different parents.

Comment: @Igor рекурсивно это если у автора на форме кнопки в контейнерах лежат. Например, кнопка в панели, а панель на форме.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если просто на форме, то вот такой foreach:

```
        foreach (Control ctrls in Controls)
        {
            Button bufButton = ctrls as Button;
            if (bufButton != null)
            {
                bufButton.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

**UPD**

Более изящное решение:

```
foreach (Button bufButton in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    bufButton.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: можно чуть проще `foreach (Control ctrls in Controls.OfType<Button>()){bufButton.Visible = false;}`

Comment: @tym32167 Да, действительно, добавил в ответ